Could a country ban its citizens from emigrating?
In the US, there is a law that says citizens outside the country must file US taxes even if they don't have to pay. The law is enforced in other countries despite the US not having jurisdiction over these countries.
This raises an interesting question. Could a country pass a law banning its citizens from gaining permanent residency in another country and compel other countries to enforce it through similar means as the US tax law?
I don't mean could any country pass such a law if it wanted to. Of course somewhere could. But if they did, would other countries recognize it and refuse to grant visas to citizens of said country?

The law is enforced in other countries despite the US not having jurisdiction over these countries. How do they do that? The US may demand tax to be paid, but it can only take action within its territority. So it's possible they could take payments from the citizen's domestic accounts.

Countries have tried, including the U.S. These laws haven't been terribly effective.

You might say that US tax law is enforced in other countries but it is not enforced  by other countries.

do you mean the US forms that some foreign banks are requiring US citizens to fill out? And FATCA (foreign account tax compliance act) which requires non-US banks to report accounts that may be held by a US citizen?

"there is a law that says citizens outside the country must file US taxes even if they don't have to pay" They are only required to file a tax return if their income is above a certain threshold (the same as for people in the US). If they have minimal or no income, they do not have to file.

The US tax code is not enforced in other countries
In countries with tax treaties with the USA, the authorities work together to avoid double taxation and to ensure that information is shared, but they don’t collect each other’s taxes or arrest people who don’t pay the other’s taxes. For example, Australia will tell the USA what a US taxpayer has reported about their income and tax payments, but they won’t be up the USA’ tax collector.
Several countries ban emigration by their citizens
North Korea is a well known example.
Whether a foreign country will return people is a matter of that foreign country’s law. Unless the person claims asylum, almost all countries will deport illegal immigrants. In fact, that was a major issue in a recent US election.
Many, many more refuse to allow citizens to renounce their citizenship or acknowledge dual citizenship
For example, as far as China is concerned a Chinese-USA citizen is just a Chinese citizen. If such a person is arrested in China, any demands by the USA for consular access will be heard as requests.
Greece is another such country. Many young expatriates returning to the old country for a holiday have found their trip extended as the Greek government insists on them doing their compulsory military service.

as far as China is concerned a Chinese-USA citizen is just a Chinese citizen - that's not true. As far as China is concerned, a Chinese-USA citizen is just a US citizen. India is another such country. You're confusing not recognizing dual citizenship with not permitting dual citizenship.

@littleadv sorry, you’re wrong.

Then please provide references. Like this

I suspect when the OP said "enforced in other countries" they meant "enforced on residents in other countries", not "enforced by other countries". I.e. you can't escape your US tax obligations by taking residence in another country.

You can though, unless you need anything from the US government. The IRS can prevent you from getting a new US passport but other than that there's very little the US government can do if you don't pay your taxes and have no nexus in the US at all.

For the title: Could a country ban its citizens from emigrating?
Yes
A country could ban its citizens from emigrating. Some countries do (e.g.: North Korea) or have done so (e.g.: The Soviet Union).
However the enforcement would be on these countries themselves, and other countries would not have to collaborate with that. Some countries, that depend on the country imposing the ban, would collaborate and return potential emigrants, but for most parts once the person found a way to leave the country they would be able to stay out of it. Usually this was done through the refugee asylum process.
To your claims and questions in the body:

In the US, there is a law that says citizens outside the country must file US taxes even if they don't have to pay

Actually that's not  true. 26 USC 6012 doesn't make any particular requirements for citizens outside the country.

The law is enforced in other countries despite the US not having jurisdiction over these countries.

This is also not true. The law is not enforced in other countries, the law is enforced in the US. If a US citizen fails to file or pay taxes when required the US government can do nothing to them in the country where they live. But it can do things that affect them in the US. For example, not renew their passport, or put liens on their US properties.

Could a country pass a law banning its citizens from gaining permanent residency in another country and compel other countries to enforce it through similar means as the US tax law?

We've determined that the US tax law doesn't actually compel any other country to enforce anything. But to your question, yes a country could theoretically pass such laws, but compelling other countries to collaborate would be much harder. That would be a political question that requires that other country's government to want to collaborate. Depending on levers of political pressure one country may have on another they may exert levels of cooperation. But that would not be because of the law passed, but because of an international treaty agreed on. Even FATCA, a US law requiring foreign banks to report information about their US clientele as a condition to doing business in the US required certain international treaties and agreements to be signed.

Actually, the mechanism of secondary sanctions makes it very unpleasant for foreign banks to deal with US citizens abroad. So de facto other countries help, under the threat of economic penalties.

Yeah, the US has quite a bit of influence on others through its political, economical, or military pressure. The wikipedia article on FATCA is a bit dated, but lists quite a few issues with that particular law and its implementation, and how it affects Americans abroad and foreign entities operating in the US.
